# How to supersede a GPO that is higher on the tree

Tags: group-policy

I have a Domain at the top level, there is a policy that prevents users from launching applications. (I don't have access to change the top level)

There is a OU (lets call it SiteA). I can manage any GPO under my Site.

How can I supersede the policy coming from the top? (I need to allow one computer to run those applications that are blocked by the top level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [TOP LEVEL] parent GPO policies are `enforced`, then there is nothing you can do to to override that and make some other policy setting less restrictive than the parent policy allows. If they do NOT `enforce` the policy in the top parent level GPO, you can `block inheritance`, and your policy should propagate and become effective.

> You can block inheritance for a domain or organizational unit.
>   Blocking inheritance prevents Group Policy objects (GPOs) that are
>   linked to higher sites, domains, or organizational units from being
>   automatically inherited by the child-level.
>
> **To block inheritance**
>
> In the Group Policy Management Console (GPMC) console tree,
>   double-click the forest containing the domain or organizational unit
>   (OU) for which you want to block inheritance for GPO links, and then
>   do one of the following:
>
> To block inheritance of the GPO links of an entire domain,
>   double-click Domains, and then right-click the domain.
>
> To block inheritance for an OU, double-click `Domains`, double-click
>   the domain containing the OU, and then right-click the OU.
>
> Click `Block Inheritance`
>
> Additional considerations
>
> To complete this procedure, you must have Link GPOs permission for the
>   domain or OU.
>
> If a domain or OU is set to block inheritance, it will appear with a
>   blue exclamation mark in the console tree.
>
> GPO links that are enforced cannot be blocked from the parent
>   container.

**RESOURCE:** https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731076.aspx

**SCREEN SHOTS**

[image: Block Inheritance]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I block Inheritance at the location you showed (image), it will block all policies from the top. We just want to block 1 of those policies for 1 specific computer. Policies from the top include the proxy server settings, favorites, WSUS update server names, etc. Is there another route?